# $group with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a question in MongoDB query.
I have the following users collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa03bf97d6e1d28a020f488"),
    "name":"A1",
     "interests" : [ 
        ObjectId("5aa03b877d6e1d28a020f484"), 
        ObjectId("5aa03bb47d6e1d28a020f485")
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5affd69339f67335303ddf77"),
    "name":"A2",
     "interests" : [ 
        ObjectId("5aa03b877d6e1d28a020f484")
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5affd69339f673ddfjfhri45"),
    "name":"A3",
     "interests" : [ 
        ObjectId("5aa03bb47d6e1d28a020f485"), 
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5affd69339f67365656ddfg4f"),
    "name":"A4",
     "interests" : [ 
        ObjectId("5aa16eb8890cbb4c582e8a38"), 
    ]
}
```

The interests collection look li the following example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa16eb8890cbb4c582e8a38"),
    "name" : "Swimming",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa03bb47d6e1d28a020f485"),
    "name" : "Basketball",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa03b877d6e1d28a020f484"),
    "name" : "Fishing",
}
```

I want to write a query that counts for the interests types of all users: 
the expected result is like:

```
 [
    {
        "name":"fishing"
        "count":21 
    },
    {
        "name":"Basketball"
        "count":15
    }
]
```

Thanks for helpers :)

Comment: Still the below answer doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you have mongodb 3.6 then you can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Intrest.collection.name,
    "let": { "interests": "$interests" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$interests" ] },
        "name": "Swimming",
      }}
    ],
    "as": "interests"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$interests" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$interests.name",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": "$_id", "count": 1
  }}
])
```

And if you want to group with interests `name`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Intrest.collection.name,
    "let": { "interests": "$interests" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$interests" ] } }}
    ],
    "as": "interests"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$interests" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$interests.name",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": "$_id", "count": 1
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi, the name should be the name of the interest, for example there are 4 users that have interest in "Swimming"

Comment: Hi, I added the interest collection example

Comment: The result is the list users but with the interest name instead of the ID and it's not the purpose. the expected result is the COUNT/ SUM of users that have "swiiming" in their interest

Comment: @RanAlcobi Please check the updated two answers... It will definitely work

Comment: Hi Antony, the swimming was only example. the result should be "For each interest -> get the number (count) of users have it in their interests array"

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$interests'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$name',
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
)
```